# Altair: geo_shape doesn't work with selection

Tags: altair, vega-lite, vega

I am working on a Choropleth map that will display the similarities between different states. So when you select a state from a dropdown, the map will show the similarity it has to other states.

For this, I am using 2 datasets:

- [DatasetA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f5XO.png): a long-form dataframe, with 3 columns: State 1, State 2, and the similarity between them.
- [DatasetB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLmyd.png): a GeoDataFrame that contains the geometry of each state.

When I try to plot this without the selection, then it works:

```
alt.Chart(gdf).mark_geoshape(
).encode(
    color='Similarity:O',
    tooltip = ['Similarity:Q']
).properties(
    projection={'type': 'albersUsa'},
    width=700,
    height=400
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='State',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'State', source.columns.values)
)
```

But once I add the selection, then it only works when I select Wyoming (the last state in Dataset A). When I select other states, the plot disappears.

```
input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=source.State.unique())
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['Similarity_to'], bind=input_dropdown ,init={'Similarity_to': 'New York'})

alt.Chart(gdf).mark_geoshape(
).encode(
    color='Similarity:Q',
    tooltip = ['Similarity:Q']
).properties(
    projection={'type': 'albersUsa'},
    width=700,
    height=400
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='State',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'State', source.columns.values)
).transform_filter(
    selection
).add_selection(
    selection
)
```

Here's a clip that demonstrates it: https://www.loom.com/share/292e8b1a80344cf5a998a54f453ece2c

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this with the vega sample datasets to figure out if there is something with your data or code and to make it easier for others to reproduce? Here is an example to start from https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/choropleth.html

Comment: It works with the example data. But that data is different. My DatasetA has multiple values that match the lookup key. E.g. each state is compared to the other state, which means that I have 2500 rows of data, and each state appears in my key column 50 times. But the lookup matches the first occurrence of the key.

Here's a link to the code with my datasets and to the code with the vega datasets: https://deepnote.com/project/altairstackoverflow--zl7Wx2tQQ22U3D1cLcodA/%2Fnotebooks%2Fstates.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by using a transform_fold. The problem is that the transform_lookup only matches once, so if there are multiple matches in the dataset, it ignores them. So you have to use a wide-form dataset and then use the `transform_fold` to convert it back into long-form.

```
input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=source.State.unique())
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['Similarity_to'], bind=input_dropdown ,init={'Similarity_to': 'New York'})

alt.Chart(gdf).mark_geoshape(
   stroke='black'
).encode(
   color='Similarity:Q',
   tooltip = ['Similarity:Q']
).properties(
   projection={'type': 'albersUsa'},
   width=700,
   height=400
).transform_lookup(
   lookup='State',
   from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'State', source.columns.values)
).transform_fold(
   source.drop('State',axis=1).columns.values, # Preserve the State column, fold the rest
   ['Similarity_to','Similarity']
).transform_filter(
   selection
).add_selection(
   selection
)
```

I actually tried this before asking the question. But it turns out I did the transformations in the wrong order. The order of transformations matters!

You can find the full code here: https://deepnote.com/project/altairstackoverflow--zl7Wx2tQQ22U3D1cLcodA/%2Fnotebooks%2Fstates.ipynb#00011-ed9a9249-2c34-412c-a091-d87d0ddb457d